# Django URL pattern with different roots

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have two URL patterns that both exist in the same application that I'm working on getting set up.

I need urls like the following to work.

- http://www.domain.com/p/12345
- http://www.domain.com/s/12345

However, both of these live in the same django application.

My main urls.py looks something like this for handling the /p/12345 urls.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

(r'^p/', include('myproject.myapp.urls')),
)
```

and my urls.py for the application is similar. but this still only handles the /p/12345 urls.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myproject.myapp.views',

(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'some_view'),
)
```

My issue is that both are almost identical but just have a different prefixes.  How can I do this for both the /p/12345 and /s/12345 urls.  I've read through the documentation but wasn't able to figure this one out. I've thought of 'sloppy' ways to do this with 2 urls.py files, but I know there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a URLs file with an empty pattern. You could do this:

main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'foo/', 'foo_view'),
    (r'^', include('myproject.myapp.urls')),
)
```

app urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('puzzlequest.pq.views',
    (r'^p/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'some_view'),
    (r'^s/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'other_view'),
)
```

Note that other routes (like `foo/`) have to come first.

Comment: Is there a way to have the root path, i.e. `http://www.example.com/`, defined in the included URLconf and not in the root URLconf? Can't seem to make it work.